# After ApiPlatform migrates from 3.1 to 3.2, my Denormalizer crashes because it's sent to ValidationExceptionNormalizer

Tags: php, symfony, decorator, api-platform.com

Inspired by the awesome [tutorial of Ryan Weaver about ApiPlatform on SymfonyCast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/normalizer-aware#also-decorating-the-denormalizer), I created a Normalizer and a Denormalizer to manage groups normalization and denormalization.

The `GroupsDenormalizer` decorates `api_platform.serializer.normalizer.item`
The `GroupsNormalizer` decorates `api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item`
I used the `#[AsDecorator]` attribute to do it.

All works! My test cover 100% of code. There is no deprecations.
As soon as I upgrade from ApiPlatform 3.1.20 to 3.2.0, my code fails and Api is no more available.

> TypeError: ApiPlatform\Symfony\Validator\Serializer\ValidationExceptionNormalizer::__construct(): Argument #1 ($decorated) must be of type Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface, App\Security\GroupsDenormalizer given, called in /srv/app/var/cache/test/ContainerCco4qUx/App_KernelTestDebugContainer.php on line 2484

I don't understand why dependency injection sent my denormalizer as argument of ValidationExceptionNormalizer constructor.

I tried to find documentation about migration from 3.1 to 3.2 (without success).
I tried to update the recipe of api-platform.
I tried to change priority.
I tried to define decoration in `services.yaml`.

As soon as I delete the `GroupsDenormalizer.php` file, Api is available again. (but my code fails because my denormalizer has a job to do :) )

What did I miss? Do you have an idea?

Below, you can find the code of these two classes.

```php
#[AsDecorator(decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item', priority: 64)]
readonly class GroupsNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private NormalizerInterface $decorated,
        private GroupsGenerator     $generator,
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * @return array<string, bool>
     */
    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            Character::class => true,
            User::class => true,
        ];
    }

    public function normalize(mixed $object, string $format = null, array $context = []): float|int|bool|\ArrayObject|array|string|null
    {
        if (true /* $object instanceof ResourceInterface */) {
            $complement = $this->generator->generateReadingGroups($object);
            if (!key_exists('groups', $context)) {
                $context['groups'] = [];
            }
            $context['groups'] = array_merge($context['groups'], $complement);
        }

        return $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
    }

    public function setSerializer(SerializerInterface $serializer): void
    {
        if ($this->decorated instanceof SerializerAwareInterface) {
            $this->decorated->setSerializer($serializer);
        }
    }

    public function supportsNormalization(mixed $data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }
}
```

```php
#[AsDecorator(decorates: 'api_platform.serializer.normalizer.item', priority: 64)]
readonly class GroupsDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private DenormalizerInterface $decorated,
        private GroupsGenerator       $generator,
    ) {
    }

    public function denormalize(mixed $data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): mixed
    {
        if (key_exists('operation', $context) && $context['operation'] instanceof Operation) {
            $complement = $this->generator->generateWritingGroups($context['operation'], $type);
            if (!key_exists('groups', $context)) {
                $context['groups'] = [];
            }
            $context['groups'] = array_merge($context['groups'], $complement);
        }

        return $this->decorated->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
    }

    /**
     * @return array<string, bool>
     */
    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            Character::class => true,
            User::class => true,
        ];
    }

    public function setSerializer(SerializerInterface $serializer): void
    {
        if ($this->decorated instanceof SerializerAwareInterface) {
            $this->decorated->setSerializer($serializer);
        }
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization(mixed $data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format, $context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My getSupportedTypes wasn't excluding correctly a lot of classes.

```php
    /**
     * @return array<string, bool>
     */
    public function getSupportedTypes(?string $format): array
    {
        return [
            Character::class => false,
            User::class => false,
            '*' => null,
        ];
    }
```